# android and ptrace injection, intercept not working

Tags: android, c

I'm trying to intercept faccessat calls from an process and manipulate it's return code but I can't seem to be able to make it work. My library is injected perfectly file but I see no logs regaring faccessat calls.

```
04-23 02:55:07.798  1546  1546 I Test: ptraceAttach success
04-23 02:55:07.801  1546  1546 E Test: getRemoteFunctionAddr path: /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so, localModuleAddr: 0x794CC51000, remoteModuleAddr: 0x704D31E000, localModuleAddr: 0x794CC51000, remoteFuncAddr: 0x704D35C1B0
04-23 02:55:07.802  1546  1546 I Test: Mmap Function Address: 0x704d35c1b0
04-23 02:55:07.802  1546  1546 E Test: lr_val: 482331451392
04-23 02:55:07.803  1546  1546 I Test: ptraceContinue success
04-23 02:55:07.803  1546  1546 E Test: ptrace_call mmap success. return value=B400006E64859C70, pc=704D31E000
04-23 02:55:07.803  1546  1546 I Test: Remote Process Map Address: 0xb400006e64859c70
04-23 02:55:07.806  1546  1546 E Test: getRemoteFunctionAddr path: /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so, localModuleAddr: 0x794FE4C000, remoteModuleAddr: 0x7052AE3000, localModuleAddr: 0x794FE4C000, remoteFuncAddr: 0x7052AE4020
04-23 02:55:07.807  1546  1546 E Test: dlopen getRemoteFuncAddr: 0x7052ae4020
04-23 02:55:07.810  1546  1546 E Test: getRemoteFunctionAddr path: /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libdl.so, localModuleAddr: 0x794FE4C000, remoteModuleAddr: 0x7052AE3000, localModuleAddr: 0x794FE4C000, remoteFuncAddr: 0x7052AE4040
04-23 02:55:07.811  1546  1546 E Test: dlerror getRemoteFuncAddr: 0x7052ae4040
04-23 02:55:07.811  1546  1546 E Test: dlopen getRemoteFuncAddr: 0x7052ae4020
04-23 02:55:07.811  1546  1546 E Test: lr_val: 482331451392
04-23 02:55:07.812  1546  1546 I Test: ptraceContinue success
04-23 02:55:07.812 26930 26930 I Test: The code has been loaded into memory.
04-23 02:55:07.813  1546  1546 I Test: ptrace_call dlopen success, Remote module Address: 0xa31730d07aa12b59
04-23 02:55:07.813  1546  1546 I Test: ptraceDetach success
04-23 02:55:07.813  1546  1546 W Test: Inject Result: 0
```

You can see that the library was injected, from **The code has been loaded into memory.** which is is sent from the injected library, but no sign of **faccessat** messages.

My code was based on: https://github.com/gianlucaborello/libprocesshider and injected into the process with https://github.com/reveny/Android-DLL-Injector

Also from strace, I can clearly see that `faccessat` was called at one point: `faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/data/data/org.raslin777.advancedLogging", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "logging.hz"

/*
 * Every file with this name will be excluded
 */
static const char* file_to_filter = "secret.txt";

#define DECLARE_FACCESSAT(faccessat)                                    \
static int (*original_##faccessat)(int, const char*, int, int) = NULL;  \
                                                                        \
int faccessat(int dirfd, const char* pathname, int mode, int flags)      \
{                                                                       \
    if(original_##faccessat == NULL) {                                  \
        original_##faccessat = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, #faccessat);             \
        if(original_##faccessat == NULL)                                \
        {                                                               \
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in dlsym: %s\n", dlerror());         \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                        \
        }                                                               \
    }                                                                   \
                                                                        \
    char* filename = strrchr(pathname, '/');                            \
    if(filename == NULL) {                                              \
        filename = (char*)pathname;                                     \
    } else {                                                            \
        filename++;                                                     \
    }                                                                   \
                                                                        \
    LOGI("faccessat: %s\n", filename);                                  \
                                                                        \
    return original_##faccessat(dirfd, pathname, mode, flags);           \
}

DECLARE_FACCESSAT(faccessat);

__attribute__((constructor))
void init(void) {
    LOGI("The code has been loaded into memory.\n");
}
```

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fPIC
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -shared

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```